# Links to magento connect

Tags: discussion

I did a [simple search](https://magento.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22*.magentocommerce.com%2Fmagento-connect%22) and found over 1k posts that mention links to the already dead [Magento Connect](https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/magento-connect-moving-marketplace).

I have no idea what do about these links.
Let the suggestions flow.

Comment: I don't understand enough about Magento to know how serious this problem is. How harmful would it be to just let the links remain? The announcement you linked to says stuff is being moved to another service (the "Marketplace" thing), and from a spot check, the existing links redirect (not very helpfully, but better than nothing).

Comment: @Pops Sorry for getting back so late. I totally forgot about your comment. The announcement I linked says that stuff is being moved to another service, but not everything gets moved. The magento marketplace concept is the one that moved, but all the code that existed has to be resubmitted to the new service. Not everyone is going to do that, so not every link is going to be matched.

Answer (score 3):

@Marius maybe we can add a note to such questions saying that Magento Connect was closed and that links pointing to that site do not work anymore? Maybe using some kind of mass update?

Eg. note like in [How can I add customer attribute in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/50039/how-can-i-add-customer-attribute-in-magento-2)

Comment: I don't think I have access to a mass update tool

Comment: @marius it still makes sense for me to add such disclaimer note to questions/answers then - another solution would be replacing links with something, but I can't see any idea what it could be.

Comment: Yes, a disclaimer is a good idea, but who's going to edit 1k+ posts? Hint: not me.

Comment: We can split, I can edit... 50. If we make search query which shows not edited ones, it should be easy for someone else to continue editing.

Comment: i am fully agreed with Wojtek. then if the moderators send message to all users as please edit the answers which have dead url's . otherwise it might be deleted. If they send like this. sure they will modify.
@Marius, i am strongly expected that sure you will respond and you can take action sir

Comment: I cannot send a message to all users. Even if I could, that would be a bit spammy and a lot of people will ignore it.

Comment: @Marius, then you may remove that content or delete directly. why because, there is no use with not existed data. and that might be useful to cleanup our magento stak exchnge